# How to migrate a JBoss Singleton Service from JBoss AS 6 to JBoss AS 7?

Tags: singleton, ejb, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

we have some services implemented on JBoss AS 6 as singleton services that we wish to migrate to JBoss AS 7.

These services are declared on the jboss-service.xml file wich is on the EJB package in something like the code below:

```xml
<mbean name="some.cool.package:service=SomeService-controller" code="org.jboss.ha.singleton.HASingletonController">

    <attribute name="HAPartition"><inject bean="HAPartition" /></attribute>
    <attribute name="TargetName">scod:service=SomeService</attribute>
    <attribute name="TargetStartMethod">startWatcher</attribute>
    <attribute name="TargetStopMethod">stopWatcher</attribute>

 </mbean>
```

Well, when we try to deploy it on JBoss 7, we see a huge `ClassNotFoundException` telling us that the class `org.jboss.ha.singleton.HASingletonController` doesn't exists. And it really doesn't on JBoss AS 7.

So here is my question: how can we migrate it to the newer version? Which class acts as this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an *official* example:

http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/cluster-ha-singleton/

https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart/tree/jdf-2.1.0.Final/cluster-ha-singleton

Comment: I used that example and it works fine. A bit too much work for my taste though, it really should be easier to configure.

Comment: @Magnilex yes, jboss-7 is certainly rough on edges regarding configuration and management. What makes it OK is that it became much more "Enterprise"-ready in turn.